# cannot insatll python plugin though I can see pip3 installation goes well

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-venv, minio, pyvenv

I am facing a very strange issue
I followed this video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=huoXr1pbzUQ

and here is the steps I took:

```
virtualenv -p /usr/local/bin/python3.7 .venv
source .venv/bin/activate
pip3 install minio
pip3 freeze > requirements.txt
```

So now I expect I should have minio installed but when I import it I get:

[image]

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/xxxx/PycharmProjects/minio/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from minio import Minio
ImportError: cannot import name 'Minio' from 'minio' (/xxx/PycharmProjects/minio/minio.py)
```

So if I get that right it means minio has not been isnatlled

Any Idea?

Comment: You are using a text editor tooltip to determine that there is a problem. You should instead run the program and read the stack trace. The problem is likely that your text editor doesn't know to use virtualenv, and how would it anyway?

Comment: I did run it and errore I will update the post

Comment: @snek_case Please see the update

Comment: You need to rename the file you are working on because it's name conflicts with the module you installed.

Comment: @jordanm is correct. If you have a file called `minio.py` in that directory then you will have problems.

Comment: Thanks @jordanm worked please add it as an answer :)